# Possible Local DNS Servers With Hashing?

Tags: hash

DNS is centralized across several servers to stop the following:

1. Querying the IP for the domain name.
2. Continuously querying the domain name to do #1.
3. Changing an entry to the database.

What if you:

1. Use the same servers as distributors of a file, each holding a private key.
2. The file includes a line for each entry in the original database.
3. For each entry, with its entry as (domain, IP),
4. Find n that has the property (hashB(domain)+n)%(256^4)=IP.
5. The entry for the file is (hashA(domain), encrypt(pk, n). (you cannot derive the hashA of something with the hashB of it and vice versa, and one of them are computationally intensive.)

I see that this does not allow for changes in DNS nor dynamic distribution, but with anti-DOS in place would this constitute a solution to DNS poisoning? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: This appears to be a question about the DNS protocol, not cryptography. DNS is a highly distributed key/value store organized as a tree, that stores many more record types than IPv4 addresses. And I don't completely get your proposal, but once a computationally intensive hash would have been computed, the same query can be replayed. Also, the way the vast majority of domain names get compromised is by people having their registrar's account compromised, usually just due to weak/reused passwords.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a new & invented protocol rather than a cryptographic implementation.